# Is there any possibility to add Sub-project to current Project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can anyone suggest me like:

I had done one project by using Objective-C. And I had an requirement to keep one button and If any user tap on that and it needs to open "https://github.com/Block-Equity/stellar-ios-wallet" (Swift) inside my app.

If user want to come back to Parent app from Sub-Project.. He can..

How can I keep 2 separate projects in One project and need to operate two projects while run-time?

Comment: use workspace to embed two projects

Comment: He @Vinodh, Thanks for your reply.. Can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: and how to access of Project B in ProjectA in current

Comment: Please have a look at https://medium.com/@OddNetworks/using-xcode-workspaces-to-develop-with-the-oddsdk-ee4c0931b30e